# Why is the nonlocal assignment of this variable not considered a previous binding?

Tags: python, scope, documentation, local

`spam` is assigned as `nonlocal` in the `do_nonlocal()` function, which, according to the Python docs, changes *scope_test's* binding of `spam`. But the docs also state that there was no previous binding for `spam` before the global assignment. `do_nonlocal()` is called before `do_global()`, which extends the scope of `spam` to `scope_test()`. Why, then, is `spam` considered binded only after it's been declared `global`, even though the docs seem to state otherwise?

> Note how the `local` assignment (which is default) didn’t change *scope_test's* binding of `spam`. *The `nonlocal` assignment changed scope_test's binding of `spam`, and the `global` assignment changed the module-level binding.*

> *You can also see that there was no previous binding for `spam` before the `global` assignment.*

```
def scope_test():
    def do_local():
        spam = "local spam"

    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"

    def do_global():
        global spam
        spam = "global spam"

    spam = "test spam"
    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", spam)
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)

scope_test()
print("In global scope:", spam)
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what the behavior you expect from that code is, and how it differs from the actual behavior?

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXugs4B3lwU) by [mcoding](https://www.youtube.com/@mCoding) is the ultimate in explaining all the variations of the scope of variables around nested functions.

Comment: Python decides the binding of each version of `spam` at its compile time. (I'm going to look at the video next, but I think that once compiled, each variable never changes scope)

Comment: From the video: "Lookups happen at *runtime*, but locations (bindings) decided at *compile* time".

Comment: @quamrana Thank you, I'll check out the video.

Comment: @Brian61354270 My issue is with what the docs state about ```spam``` not being previously binded before being assigned as ```global``` in ```do_global()```, while also stating that ```do_nonlocal()``` changes the binding of ```spam```. Since ```do_nonlocal()``` is called first, does that not imply that ```spam``` *was* previously binded *before* being assigned as ```global``` in ```do_global()```? Maybe there's some fundamental piece of knowledge I'm missing that's causing the confusion, but I'm interpreting this as a contradiction.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've included the entire code example from the doc. But here's the link, anyway (Section 9.2.1): [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#id2]

Comment: @maltuin there is no contradiction. the global variable `spam` was unbound prior to the call to `do_global`. That is a different variable to the local variable in `scope_test`. There is no contradiction

Comment: "Why, then, is spam considered binded only after it's been declared global," it's not. It is unbound *until `spam = "global spam"` is executed*. The global statement doesn't bind the variable.

Comment: "which extends the scope of spam to scope_test()." *no!*. The scope isn't "extended" There are *two different variables*. Variables have *precisely one scope*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The document specifically states that there was no previous binding for ```spam``` before the ```global``` ***assignment***. It also states that the binding of ```spam``` was ***changed*** after being declared ```nonlocal```. What does *changed* mean in this context, if not that ```spam``` ***was*** binded by its ```nonlocal``` assignment?

Comment: @maltuin the `nonlocal` statement changes *which variables the assignment statement applies to*. But the docs are saying that the *assignment* changed the binding, not the `nonlocal` statement. And the docs are 100% right *that there was no previous binding for `spam` in the global scope*. Because that variable *did not exist* until it was assigned to, which happens when `do_global` was called

Comment: The word `"changed"` in the documentation refers to what is happening at compile time. At compile time, there may be a time when a variable is thought to be in one state, but upon seeing a local assignment, the *compiler* *changes* its mind about the binding.

Comment: @quamrana it doesn't, actually. It is referring to the *assignment* which does change the binding of a variable. It's saying that `spam = "local spam"` did not change the binding of the `test_scope`'s `spam` variable, and that `spam = "nonlocal spam"` does.

Comment: @maltuin The docs are using to phrase "X's binding of `spam`" to try to disambiguate between the different variables named spam that live in different scopes/namespaces. _"The nonlocal assignment changed `scope_test`'s binding of spam"_ means that inside the nonlocal assignment, the identifier `spam` refers to the `spam` variable in `scope_test`'s scope (as opposed to a local variable in `do_nonlocal`'s scope, or a module-level variable). _"the global assignment changed the module-level binding"_ means that inside the global assignment, `spam` refers to the module-level variable `spam`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what you're not understanding, but, but here's the basic explanation.

You have three different variables all name `spam`.  The global variable, the variable inside `scope_test`, and the variable inside `do_local`.  Each of your inner functions changes a different one of these.

When you write `print(...., spam)` inside `scope_test`, you are seeing the last value assigned to the `scope_test` version of `spam`.  When you call that same print statement at global level, you are seeing the global value.

Perhaps the part you are missing is that Python "compiles" a function before evaluating it. Python knows what variables are used within each scope before that scope is evaluated.  Hence `spam` exists as a variable within `scope_test` before `scope_test` is called.  The `non_local` knows to use this `scope_test`, even though it hasn't been assigned a value yet.

---

Another example that may help you understand what's going on.

```
spam = 10

def function1():
    print(spam)

def function2():
    print(spam)
    spam = 11
```

You'll notice that `function1()` works fine, but `function2()` gives you an error.  Why? Because Python sees that `spam` is assigned a value in `function2()`, and therefore `spam` must be a local variable.  Hence all references to `spam` are local variables in `function2()`, and printing `spam` fails.  But in `function1()`, `spam` is just the global.

Comment: I understand how the value of ```spam``` changes based on its scope. I'm confused about what the Python docs state in regards to there being no binding of ```spam``` before it was assigned globally, when just before they stated that the binding of ```spam``` was changed when it was declared as ```nonlocal```. And since ```do_nonlocal()``` was called first, does that not imply that ```spam``` *was* previously binded before being given a ```global``` assignment?

Comment: @maltuin I think there's a framing issue. You're still referring to `spam` as if it's one variable. But it's not. You have three, completely distinct, entirely unrelated variables. You could change them to being named `spam1`, `spam2`, and `spam3` with zero difference in behavior. The docs passage is saying that assigning to `spam2` doesn't affect `spam3`, _because those are different variables_.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thanks for the clarification. I stated in a previous comment that I must be missing something fundamental.

Comment: Added additional info.

Answer (score 1):

I think your fundamental misunderstanding is that there are *two different* `spam` variables that exist in different scopes (three, actually, if we include the one in `do_local`). The global `spam` variable is *indeed* unbound prior to the execution of `spam = "global spam"` when `do_global` is called inside of `scope_test` (it isn't bound by the global statement actually, it remains unbound until it is *assigned to*).

The scope of the variable isn't *extended*. Variables can only have a single scope.

Comment: My new understanding is that there ***are*** three seperate instances of ```spam```, as @Brian61354270 stated.